# facebook webhook not verifying php

Tags: php, facebook, bots

my webhook url is been called by facebook as i can see from the acces logs. but i get error logs (Undefined index: hub_verify_token).

i have tried to figure this out but not getting any heads way. i will appreciate it if someone could kindly assist.

thanx.
my php code is bellow.

```
 $hubVerifyToken = 'XXX';
  $accessToken =   "XXXXX";
   if ($_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'] === $hubVerifyToken) {
 echo 
 $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
 exit;
 }
  // handle bot's anwser
   $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
   $senderId = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
    $messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
 $response = null;
  //set Message
   if($messageText == "hi") {
    $answer = "Hello";
      }
     $response = null;
      $response = [
    'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId],
    'message' => [ 'text' => $answer ]
    ]; 
    $ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/messages?access_token='.$accessToken);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($response));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if(!empty($input)){
  echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
  }
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: it means that `$_REQUEST` does not contain 'hub_verify_token' key. Can you try dumping `$_REQUEST` to see what all keys it contains.

Comment: i get an empty array "Array()".

Comment: that's the reason you are getting Undefined index: hub_verify_token. any reason you are expecting `hub_verify_token` in the request?

Comment: yes.. so according to some sample facebook bot, 
 you should be expecting the parameter in the $_request. 

please see link 
https://medium.com/@nadeem.manzoor0/facebook-messenger-platform-web-hook-setup-in-php-893ead06746b

Comment: so the article does not assume that parameter is always there. please note the author of that article has put a check `if (isset($_GET['hub_verify_token']))`. I think you should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook before proceeding with this article.

Comment: i understand the article and the documentation. so the author in the articles check for the existence of the parameter. if the parameter is there the script wont work either. (according to my test). 
whiles debuging i removed the isset. 

im not too sure why im not getting the parameter even tho the set up has been done just as described in the documentation. 

i will keep looking anyways.

Comment: additionally, you should take a look at this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup as well.

Comment: @GauravSinghFaujdar  i have actually gone through that do.  the sample is in nodejs and the parameter is ['hub.verify_token']. but for most of the PHP samples its ['hub_verify_token']. but then again the $_REQUEST comes empty

Comment: did you follow 'Configure the webhook for your app' as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/app-setup

Comment: yes i did all that